# converting variable like string content to real variable in python

Tags: python, string, variables, split

I have string variable which contains "variable" like content as shown below.

```
str1="type=gene; loc=scaffold_12875; ID=FBgn0207418; name=Dvir\GJ20278;MD5=4c62b751ec045ac93306ce7c08d254f9; length=2088; release=r1.2; species=Dvir;"
```

I need to make variables out of the string such that the variables name and values goes like this

```
type="gene"
loc="scaffold_12875"
ID="FBgn0207418"
name="Dvir\GJ20278"
MD5="4c62b751ec045ac93306ce7c08d254f9"
length=2088
release="r1.2"
species="Dvir"
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. You could, but don't.

Instead make a dictionary whose keys are the names:

```
result_dict = {}
items = str1.split(';')
for item in items:
    key, value = item.strip().split('=')
    result_dict[key] = value
```

Comment: `key, value = item.strip().split('=', 1)` will allow to use '=' in values.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this

```
class Namespace(object):
    pass

for item in str1.split(';'):
    key, value = item.strip().split('=', 1)
    setattr(Namespace, key, value)
```

You can then access your variables like so

```
Namespace.length
```